# No permission to access/ tried "chmod u+x"/.command/ file kinda opens but not rally /Hairline would appreciate it

Tags: python, shell, terminal, executable, chmod

First post on here, and I'm going to make it count... I just started to learn to program yesterday and  started with "Learning Python the hard Way".

Anyways one of the first excercises instructs me open a file through my terminal (Mac). So the instructions aren't very clear (i get that it's kind of the point), and I keep getting a not authorized to open "go to info> change settings" or something along those lines.

So I find where my file is in the terminal and add "chmod u+x" as I saw suggested on here, before the location, and it seems to work. However when it finally lets me open the file it opens it up on my text editor (atom) and won't let me open it in my terminal.

So i changed the file name to .command, and when it opens it then it only prints one line highlighting syntax erros and not what I see on the mac "quickview" or what the author shows on the screen. And I did just start learning less than 24 hours ago however   print("hello world")   and 5 identical lines don't seem wrong with no indentaion or any thing else.

I am beyond lost atm, and thinking I shoulve maybe started with "Learning Python the easy way" instead...

If anybody could walk me through what I'm doing wrong to someone whose technical expertise begins with browsing the web and a couple of excel functions, my hairline would greatly appreciate it.

TL;DR

How to get .py file to execute on the terminal and not on editor (Mac OX)

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share the exact content of your file? If it has syntax error, then something seems to be wrong. Additionaly, you an make sure that the file is exectuded through python by typing `python <filename>` in your terminal

Comment: Are you running your script from the command line?  If you get an error message then please say *exactly* what it is (in your question) - "*won't let me open it*" is not very diagnostic.

Comment: @ramrod678 : From your Mac Terminal, you use `python3 PATH/TO/YOUR/PROGRAM.py`. Use `python` instead of `python3` if you still use the old python.